# EmberJS: URL in the location bar (browser) doesn't change if user clicked on a link that has an href of '#'

Tags: ember.js

I am using Ember 1.5.0 and a typical routing code in Ember.

I use `Router.reopen({location: 'history'});` to use the location API of the browser.

In my hbs template, I have 2 links to my routes:
`{{#link-to "index"}}Home{{/link-to}}` and `{{#link-to "about"}}About{{/link-to}}`

The URL in the browser's locationbar changes if I click to one of them. (no problems with this). **BUT**, if I click on a link that has a URL of `#`, clicking again to the `{{link-to}}`s doesn't change the URL in the locationbar anymore.

Although it still renders the correct templates, but it's quite confusing since the URL in the locationbar doesn't change.

Here's a jsFiddle, although this doesn't show the issue since the location bar in jsFiddle will never change. http://jsfiddle.net/NQKvy/895/

But I've created a screen cap for this:
[image: ifredirectedtohashthenlocationbarwillnotchange]

Is there anything I missed that's causing the location bar to not change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's definitely a bug in Ember.

Stepping through the code in 1.4 or 1.5, you'll see that `Ember.HistoryLocation#setURL` is called when you click on the destroyer link that contains just the `#`. When that happens, notice that the `this.state === null`. All published version of ember back to 1.0 would not update the URL if the state was null. https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/4235 was created to fix this by mixonic, though it appears he was fixing it for iframe reasons, it's the same bug.

Because master is written using ES6 modules but the stable branch is not (yet), his code was accidentally lost during a cherry-pick conflict merge into stable [here](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/commit/07fafb8445664bc94fc68b70bb4d4cf668d1cbd9).

https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/4730 fixed this, adding the missing changes into stable.

So that brings me to:

#### This is indeed fixed and waiting on either 1.5.1 or worst case, 1.6 at the latest.

Demos:

http://static.jayphelps.com/4701-ember-1.4.0/

http://static.jayphelps.com/4701-ember-1.5.0/

[http://static.jayphelps.com/4701-ember-1.5.1+pre.5349ffcb/ (fixed)](http://static.jayphelps.com/4701-ember-1.5.1+pre.5349ffcb/)

You can follow the discussion of this bug here: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/4701#issuecomment-40788423